# How to get a certain number of inputs in one line?

Tags: python, algorithm

I want to get a certain number of inputs in one line. So I get input for example 3, then on the following line I want 3 inputs that have been split. Example: n = 3 and then the next line contains a list with 3 integers, but if it gets something different then it will `break`.

Comment: So whats the question...?

Comment: can you please show us what you tried and what did not work?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

First request the number of inputs.

```
numInputs = int(input("Number of inputs: "))
```

Split each value from the second input.

```
values = input().split(" ")
```

Validate if the length of the second input is greater than the first one and call the exit() function to close the program. If you are using a function use `return`.

```
if len(values) > numInputs:
    print("Wrong input")
    exit()
```

Convert each value to an integer.

```
for i in range(len(values)):
    values[i] = int(values[i])
```

Print all the numbers.

```
print(values)
```